# Receiving TypeError while trying to write to file in Python

Tags: python, file-io, typeerror

When I run this code:

```
tickers = re.findall(r'Process Name: (\w+)', s)

file = open("C:\Documents and Settings\jppavan\My Documents\My Dropbox\Python Scripts\Processes\GoodProcesses.txt","w")
file.write(tickers)
file.close()
```

It returns the common error:

> TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

findall() as the name indicates returns a Python *list* and not a string/buffer.

You can not write a list to file handle - how should that work?

What do you expect?

```
file.write(str(tickers))
```

for the string representation of the list?

Or

```
file.write(', '.join(tickers))
```

for a comma-separated concatenation of the list items?

Anyway...write(..) requires a string or a buffer.

Apart from that: don't call your file handle 'file'.

file() is a build-in method.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I would be fine with a string representation or comma-separated. That eliminated the error, but nothing outputs to the file, even though it should, so I should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Also, with naming the file file, that did cross my mind to not do it, but yeah...

Comment: Obiously your regular expression does not match. Take pdb and debug it.